# /socket.io/socket.io.js 404 (Not Found)

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I'm having some issues with socket.io

I have looked at all of the answers that I have seen, and I cannot find any discrepancies. Any help would be appreciated. I was also having formatting issues with pasting the code onto here so I put it onto pastebin.

http://pastebin.com/tmdXALFX

Comment: What exactly are the issues you're having? It's not good to make people you're asking for help guess what the actual problem is. Error message? Stack trace? Anything?

Comment: My answer to this question fixes it. Passport makes the route for /socket.io/socket.io.js, although I wasn't configuring it properly so the route wasn't made resulting in the 404. It was an issue for version 3 using the initialisation for 2.x, it's resolved now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

https://github.com/visionmedia/express/wiki/Migrating-from-2.x-to-3.x

Line 40 becomes

```
var server = http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});

var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
```